# How to serialize asynchronous calls with synchronized block

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using `Firebase` for my backend, and on the client (Android) side I'm trying to download a bunch of images in order. I wrapped the iterator in a `synchronized` block and I'm waiting each image to be downloaded.

```
private Object mLock = new Object();

private void downloadImages() {
   List<StorageReference> storageReferences = getStorageReferences();

   synchronized (mLock) {
      // Iterate trough all image references 
      for (StorageReference sr : storageReferences) {
         sr.getBytes(ONE_MB_BUFFER).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<byte[]> task) {
               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                  // Success, image downloaded
               }

               // Notify, that we have downloaded the image
               synchronized (mLock) {
                  mLock.notify();
               }
            }
         });

         // Await until we acquire the lock
         try {
            mLock.wait();
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The callback in the `addOnCompleteListener` does not gets called. Actually, the whole thread is locked.

Is there any other alternative to queue the download tasks? Like a single threaded executor service?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `ExecutorService` with `newSingleThreadExecutor`. If you want other customization like, timeout, you may want to use `newScheduledThreadPool`. You can create a thread-pool and execute multiple threads simultaneously.

```
public class ImageDownloadService extends IntentService {

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      downloadImages();
   }  

   private void downloadImages() {
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

      List<StorageReference> storageReferences = getStorageReferences();

      for (StorageReference sr : storageReferences) {
         Future<byte[]> future = executor.submit(new FutureImageResult(sr));

         byte[] data = null;

         try {
            data = future.get();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

         if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            // Image downloaded successfully
         }
      }
   }   

}
```

The `future` which is submitted to the executor service.

```
public class FutureImageResult implements Callable<byte[]> {

    private StorageReference mStorageReference;

    private boolean mIsFailure;

    public FutureImageResult(StorageReference storageReference) {
        mStorageReference = storageReference;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] call() throws Exception {
        Task<byte[]> task = mStorageReference.getBytes(1024 * 1024);
        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                mIsFailure = true;
            }
        });

        while (!task.isComplete() || mIsFailure);
        byte[] data = task.getResult();

        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using a BlockingQueue.

The overall idea is:

- you start a thread that continuously polls from the queue, downloads the given image and starts over
- you put all URLs into the queue
- a listener is associated either to the thread or to each image

More less the required code is:

```
final BlockingQueue<URL> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            URL url = queue.poll();
            // Download the image and notify the listener               
        }
    }
}).start();
```

This thread can be started by a Service so it can keep running and is not tied to the UI. Activities can then bind the Service to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `CountDownLatch` to lock your worker thread until the operation completes. Something like this:

```
private void downloadImages() {
   List<StorageReference> storageReferences = getStorageReferences();
   CountDownLatch waitForDownload = new CountDownLatch(storageReferences.size());
   // Iterate trough all image references 
   for (StorageReference sr : storageReferences) {
         sr.getBytes(ONE_MB_BUFFER).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<byte[]> task) {
               // Notify, that we have downloaded the image and continue
               waitForDownload.countDown();
            }
         });
   }
   // Lock until we download all images
   waitForDownload.await();
   // Continue with the rest of your serialized work having all images downloaded
   ...
}
```

References: [CountDownLatch javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).